# Not fetching the details in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<tr>
    <td width="30%" height="40" align="right">
        <label id="namemsg" for="incoming_stock">Board Name&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <input type="text" name="bName" id="bName"  size="40" value="" class="inputbox required" maxlength="50" style="border: thin solid #C1C1C1; width: 235px;height: 40px;"/>
    </td>
</tr>




function UpdateboardDetails(){

    stocksubmit=true;
    var boardId=document.getElementById("boardId").value;
    var bName=document.getElementById("bName").value;

    }
```

I am trying to fetch the value of input id:'bname'. but it is showing null. please help

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the full file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use JQuery use this

```
        var boardId=$("#boardId").val();
        var bName=$("#bName").val();
```

Comment: thanks for the code. it worked. do you have any idea that y that didn't work?